# Added a column, renamed it, and now getting SQLSTATE on sales back office

Tags: module, database, sql, database-update

I have a module that added a `foo_import` column to the `sales_flat_order` table using the proper sql folder method. I renamed this column both in the sql folder, and in the database using phpmyadmin. I have renamed it to `export_flag`. The site works fine, module works fine, can still place orders. Issue is, when I click on the sales tab on the backoffice, I get this issue.

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sales_flat_order.foo_import' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `main_table`.*, `sales_flat_order`.`foo_import` FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order` ON main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 20

#0 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/__default.php(65519): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/__default.php(54710): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/__default.php(55747): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#4 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/__default.php(56683): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#5 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/__default.php(54967): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#6 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/__default.php(32325): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#7 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/__default.php(32951): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#8 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/__default.php(32157): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getData()
#9 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid.php(533): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#10 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid.php(62): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#11 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid.php(626): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#12 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid.php(632): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
#13 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/__default.php(2612): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
#14 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/__default.php(2331): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/__default.php(2275): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)
#16 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container.php(77): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')
#17 /var/www/kute3/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid/container.phtml(36): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container->getGridHtml()
#18 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/__default.php(3418): include('/var/www/kute3/...')
#19 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/__default.php(3449): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#20 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/__default.php(3463): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#21 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#22 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#23 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/__default.php(2613): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()
#24 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/__default.php(13851): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#25 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/__default.php(2613): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#26 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/__default.php(2331): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/__default.php(2275): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#28 /var/www/kute3/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#29 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/__default.php(3418): include('/var/www/kute3/...')
#30 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/__default.php(3449): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#31 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/__default.php(3463): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#32 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#33 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/__default.php(2613): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#34 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/__default.php(28559): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#35 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/__default.php(14244): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#36 /var/www/kute3/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(95): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#37 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/__default.php(14272): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->indexAction()
#38 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/__default.php(18726): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#39 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/__default.php(18256): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#40 /var/www/kute3/includes/src/__default.php(21084): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#41 /var/www/kute3/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#42 /var/www/kute3/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#43 {main}
```

I have cleared cache and reindexed.

How can I get Magento to update it's understanding of the `sales_flat_order` table?

Comment: Did you clear the storage cache? Magento keeps an internal 'view' of the db structure.

Comment: Can you show your `grid.php` file too? I think problem persist there.

Comment: what version of magento ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that despite me clearing my cache using the `"Flush Cache Storage"` button, there was still an instance of the old column name under `var/cache/`. Deleting this resolved the issue. Unsure why flushing the cache didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the module that added the column has a Model folder, in this folder usually you can find some references to that column. I suggest that you make a search on the Module folder for `foo_import` and then replace this with the name of the new column `export_flag`.

Comment: No references to `foo_import` in the model folder, or anywhere else in the repo.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to explicitly flush/refresh the Cache storage? Try to flush it with the button in the upper right corner of the cache page.

```
"Flush Cache Storage"
```

Magento stores some model/db data in this cache. I had a similair problem once. I searched for hours. Seems Magento does a hard cache on some entities (like database fields) in this cache.